# Using HashMap and Sort it using TreeMap with Descending Key Values

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have this code to populate a `HashMap` and pass it to `TreeMap` to sort it in natural order in `Key` values.

```
    Map<Integer, String[]> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
    hashMap.put(3, new String[]{"1","2"});
    hashMap.put(2, new String[]{"1","2"});
    hashMap.put(4, new String[]{"1","2"});
    hashMap.put(1, new String[]{"1","2"});

    System.out.println(hashMap);

    Map<Integer, String[]> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String[]>(hashMap);

    System.out.println(hashMap); // Natural Order, Ascending
```

Now my problems is, How can I sort my `treeMap` in `Descending` order? I've prepared my Comparator class named `KeyComparator` that sort `Key` to descending order. Here is my code below:

```
public class KeyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if (o1 < o2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1 > o2) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The `TreeMap` has no  2 parameterized Constructor like for example `TreeMap(new KeyComparator(),hashMap)`. How can I use my `KeyComparator` class at the same time use to load the `hashMap` into my `treeMap`.

Comment: If all you need is descending natural order then you could use `new TreeMap<Integer, String[]>(hashMap).descendingMap()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like below, Create a treemap with `Comparator` and then use `putAll` method to pass the hashmap to it.

```
Map<Integer, String[]> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String[]>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        if (o1 < o2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1 > o2) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);

System.out.println(treeMap); // Descending
```

**Note:-** In the example above, I have passed an anonymous implementation of `Comparator`. You can always pass the `KeyComparator` in the constructor.

Comment: `treeMap.putAll` really helps. This is the first time I used it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not answer your question, why not simply use an Array to sort it?

```
System.out.println("map: " + hashMap);
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(hashMap.keySet());
System.out.println("unsorted keys: " + keys);
Collections.sort(keys);
System.out.println("sorted (asc) keys: " + keys);
Collections.reverse(keys);
System.out.println("sorted (desc) keys: " + keys);
```

Comment: Sorry but I need it in a TreeMap way, btw thanks for some help.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you need first to use the constructor with the key comparator which is [`TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) then use [`putAll(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-) to add all entries.

If you use **Java 8** no need to reimplement it, simply use [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) to get the reverse of the *natural ordering* as next:

```
Map<Integer, String[]> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
System.out.println(treeMap);
```

Comment: Im using **Java 7**. `treeMap.putAll` is all I need, thanks by the way to overview me in **Java 8**.

Answer (score 0):

The TreeMap has a nice method for this. You can do

```
 TreeMap<Integer, String[]> map = new TreeMap<>(hashMap);
 NavigleMap<Integer, String[]> reversedMap = map.descendingMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty TreeMap with your comparator first

```
Map<Integer, String[]> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String[]>(new KeyComparator());

treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)

You may have to tweak the syntax